# Saving to a Entity that has Many To Many relationship

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have a set of tables (ConditionTemplate and KeyWord) that have a many to many relationship.   In code I am trying to add a Keyword to a specific ConditionTemplate record.   Unfortunately, when I think I'm adding a Keyword to a specific condition I'm getting an error as if it's adding a new Keyword without being associated to a condition.

An Image of my Model:
[image]

My Code:

Global Variables Creation:

```
    EnterpriseEntities EE;
    ConditionTemplate myConditionTemplate;
```

Load Global Variables:

```
            EE = new EnterpriseEntities();
            EE.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = Myapp.EnterpriseEntityConnectionString;

            myConditionTemplate = EE.ConditionTemplates.Where(c => c.TemplateCode == "17D").FirstOrDefault();
```

The above code loads a single Condition with Many Keywords.

Available Keywords are in a listbox and the user pushed a button to select a keyword(s) to move to the condition.   This is the code that handles that.

```
                foreach (KeyWord SelectedKeyWord in ListBoxAvailableKeyWords.SelectedItems)
                {



                    KeyWord NewKeyWord = new KeyWord
                    {
                        KeyWordID = SelectedKeyWord.KeyWordID,
                        ID = SelectedKeyWord.ID,
                        Word = SelectedKeyWord.Word

                    };

                    myConditionTemplate.KeyWords.Add(NewKeyWord);



                }
```

Then the user pushes a button to save changes and I call

```
 EE.SaveChanges
```

Then I get this error:

> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the
>   entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'IX_KeyWord'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.KeyWord'. The
>   duplicate key value is (ADJUDICATION). The statement has been
>   terminated.

If I remove the code that sets the word property (Word = SelectedKeyWord.Word
) when I create the keyword object I get this error.

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation
>   failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Which tells me the word field is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to tell EF that the `KeyWord`s you selected already exist in the database and to avoid the problem you must attach them to the context:

```
foreach (KeyWord SelectedKeyWord in ListBoxAvailableKeyWords.SelectedItems)
{
    KeyWord NewKeyWord = new KeyWord
    {
        // You actually only need to set the primary key property here
        ID = SelectedKeyWord.ID
    };

    EE.KeyWords.Attach(NewKeyWord);
    myConditionTemplate.KeyWords.Add(NewKeyWord);
}
```

**Edit**

If the `KeyWord` entities are already attached to your context (because they have been loaded before with the same context for example) you can use instead:

```
foreach (KeyWord SelectedKeyWord in ListBoxAvailableKeyWords.SelectedItems)
{
    KeyWord NewKeyWord = EE.KeyWords.Find(SelectedKeyWord.ID);
    myConditionTemplate.KeyWords.Add(NewKeyWord);
}
```

Comment: No I get this error.  An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Comment: I meant Now I get this error.  Sorry for the typo.  Stepped away for 5 minutes and I couldn't edit it.  Wanted to clarify since the current statement sounds rude.  :D

Comment: @Tyddlywink: Can you check in the debugger if the IDs in the loop above are all unique? Or add a line before the foreach loop: `bool idsUnique = ListBoxAvailableKeyWords.SelectedItems.Select(i => i.ID).Distinct().Count() == ListBoxAvailableKeyWords.SelectedItems.Count();` and then check if `idsUnique` is `true` or `false`.

Comment: for my testing they are always unique because I'm only selecting one item at a time then saving the context.   The error and code appears as if I'm adding another KeyWord Entity to Keyword not the xr table.

Comment: @Tyddlywink: You can try the code in my Edit above. It looks that the `KeyWord` entities are already or still attached to the context.

Comment: That worked.  I'd like to understand why this worked and the other didn't.   Is it because I was creating a new KeyWord Entity with the same key of ID?   So instead I'm now looking for a keyword with the ID I need and adding that to the xr table?

Comment: @Tyddlywink: Yes, right. EF does not allow to have two entity objects with the same key attached to the context. `Find` retrieves the entity  object that was already in the context (or would query the database if no entity was found in the context).